# Using CleanroomLogger in a Swift script fails to resolve DefaultLogConfiguration

Tags: swift, logging, swift2, swift-playground

I'm just starting to play with Swift 2.0 for scripting and running into an issue with symbols being resolved.

Using Carthage I bootstrap from a Cartfile containing

```
github "emaloney/CleanroomLogger"
```

I am able to get CleanroomLogger working inside of Playground by:

1. Create a Workspace inside of XCode 7.1.1
2. Add the CleanroomLogger.xcodeproj file from `./Carthage/Checkouts/CleanroomLogger`
3. Create a new Playground in the project

Inside of the playground I enter the code

```
import CleanroomLogger

var logConfig = DefaultLogConfiguration.init(minimumSeverity: LogSeverity.Debug, synchronousMode: true)
Log.enable(logConfig)
Log.debug?.message("Sample message sent to debug")
Log.debug?.value("Sample value sent to debug")
```

This plays without error. I only see `()` as the output in the playground next to each `Log.debug?` call which is expected. If I open up the Console app I see two entries:

```
11/20/15 10:33:51.455 PM Cleanroom Logger[70056]:   DEBUG | <EXPR>:5 — Sample message sent to debug
11/20/15 10:33:51.455 PM Cleanroom Logger[70056]:   DEBUG | <EXPR>:6 — <String: "Sample value sent to debug">
```

So clearly I have CleanroomLogger checked out and properly built at this point.

I proceed to try and use Cleanroom Logger from a script `logger-demo.swift` located in the same directory as my Cartfile. This script is identical to the playground code with the addition of the shebang at the start

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift -F Carthage/Build/Mac

import CleanroomLogger

var logConfig = DefaultLogConfiguration.init(minimumSeverity: LogSeverity.Debug, synchronousMode: true)
Log.enable(logConfig)
Log.debug?.message("Hello from inside my Mac")
Log.debug?.value("This is a test of value")
```

Running the script results in the following output:

```
$ ./logger-demo.swift
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__TMdV15CleanroomLogger23DefaultLogConfiguration' which could not be resolved!
```

Why would this resolve in a playground but not from a swift script?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that sounds complicated ...

Maybe try [SwiftyBeaver](http://git.io/vBPuS) logger for Swift 2 instead. It is simple(!), supports colors, is fast &  is much more feature-complete.

P.S.: I am the creator :)

Comment: Adding to my Cartfile I only see an entry for SwiftyBeaver in Carthage/Builds/iOS. The script is intended to run on OS X. Is there anything that makes SwiftyBeaver iOS specific and would keep it from working on a Mac?

Comment: Not that I know and it should run under Mac, too because it does not use any special iOS libraries. Just Foundation which works on every platform.

Comment: A brand new Cartfile with only SwiftyBeaver included builds only for iOS. I'm not sure if this is an issue with how it has been configured for use in Carthage or if the XCode config needs to be updated. I'm new to both so I'm going to play but if you want broader adoption you might want to have it build for multiple platforms via Carthage out of the box.